# Which is the best way to upload multiple images to the server in android

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am using okHttp to upload multiple images(more than 10 in this case) to the server using multipartbody.
I and my friend had argument, I am saying to upload all images in a single request.
He is saying send one request at a time once the previous image is uploaded upload next one.
Which is the right thing to do, so the server works fast and no timeout occurs.

Comment: if you want send all the images to server at one time, then make sure you do it in a background Thread . sending just one image at a  time is a bad idea if you have bulk images to send to the server thats doesnt mean sending all the images at a time is a good practice. it's better you send it in a group of 5 or so

Comment: @Jois kk but can you tell me how multipart work? Will it send the images one by one, or it the request fails, is there any way to get the last successfully sent image?

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: it will send the message associated with that request not one by one. is you can get the llast image sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send Base64 format (String) like below and create one text file that contains all encoded photo as string

```
/**
     * Encodes the image to Base64.
     */
    private String encodeImage(String photoPath) {

        File imagefile = new File(photoPath);
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

and use MultipartUtility to upload file:

https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_android/blob/master/Cloudinary/src/com/cloudinary/MultipartUtility.java

Comment: Base64 encoding increases the file size by approx 33%. So I don't think its a good way to do.

Comment: for that you can Gzip rit?

Comment: Which one is better sending as file in multipart request or sending as encoded string??

Comment: Its based on your requirement/server implementation. i guess both file/encoded is best..
you can compress encoded string so that size will be reduced..!!